# Selector for "Define" Edit Menu item in iOS 5

Tags: ios, dictionary, selector, definition

I'm building my own custom Edit Menu (UIMenuController) and am using the typical

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender(id)sender
```

method to conditionally enable / disable system defaults. The typical edit methods are well documented (copy:, cut:, etc.), but I can't find anything about what method is called by the "Define" menu option to pull up the new word dictionary in iOS 5. Maybe it's hiding in plain sight, but I've spent hours looking for it, so I'd appreciate any help. Specifically, I need:

```
if (action == @selector(defineWord:)) ......
```

but give me what really goes in the place of "defineWord:"

ps - I wouldn't mind knowing what class the method belongs to, just out of curiosity (copy: belongs to UIResponderStandardEditActions, for example)

Answer (score 5):

By implementing this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(action));
}
```

I was able to see that the selector is "_define:".

Comment: My app is rejected because of _define:. Resolution center says the reason is "2.5: Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected".

Answer (score 5):

The define selector (_define:) is actually private and your app will be rejected if you use it. What I had to do to get only the Define menu item to show up in a UITextView was this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(cut:) ||
        action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(select:) ||
        action == @selector(selectAll:) ||
        action == @selector(paste:) ||
        action == @selector(delete:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right - I received my rejection letter yesterday, and I wasn't really surprised because I could tell it was private (Xcode complained). For right now I just disabled the code and removed the Define option, and I'll try a variant of what you have above in the next version.

Comment: @Michael Surran how do you remove define without using the _define selector ?

Comment: Basically I return YES for the edit menu items I want using (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender(id)sender. I return NO for everything else (which includes the _define selector).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7.1 I see these actions occurring when overriding the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method on a subclass of `UIWebView`:

```
cut:
copy:
select:
selectAll:
paste:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_define:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

Presumably the ones prefixed with an underscore are "private API" whose use subjects your app to rejection by the App Store. But I cannot really find any documentation on that one way or the other.

The ones without an underscore are defined as part of the [`UIResponderStandardEditActions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/index.html) informal protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do it without using privateAPI, return YES only for wanted Action

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(MySelector:)
    {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender]
    }
    else 
     return NO;
}
```

Enjoy ;)