# iOS app rejected as it has undocumented API -- Further steps

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My first iOS app was rejected by Apple as it contained undocumented API (used _define in selector). I found a work around.

My problem here is I don't want any more iterations with the same reason (use of undocumented API).

Does Apple lists down all undocumented APIs at once or Apple is going to reject as it found a new method with private API (I found there is no way to be 100% sure if an app contains undocumented API) ?

Comment: That depends... Remove all the usage of private api's. Otherwise your app may rejected due to the same reason in the next review

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513886/988769

Comment: I filtered google results to find a way to list down undocumented API. Please suggest if you have any way other than otool, strings, app-scanner.

Comment: @Kreiri -- I got a work around.. I want the answer if Apple lists down all undocumented API once or it sends in an iterative manner.

Comment: If it's not in documentation, it's undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

use this http://www.deploymateapp.com/

or you can validate the project before submission with iOS 5 development tools and extract private APIs.